А кому-то удалось запустить google ads rewarded?
Ситуация следующая. Сайт. html/js
Беру базовый пример google ads rewarded, где указаны ключи гугла - всё работает отлично.
Перетыкаю ключи на свои - не работает.
Уж что я только в настройках не правил. Админку всю поперенастраивал. Результат один.
Даже через средства отладки говорит, что слот не был заполнен
Ad fetch count: 1
Ad unit did not fill
Iframe type: none
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?
